# How to manually Log-out from Firebase with Redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I am not sure, if my current code is working, I just followed the documentation of firebase regarding log out.

```
export const onSignOut = () => async (dispatch) => {

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        console.log('You have log-out succesfully');
        dispatch({type: SIGN_OUT});
        Actions.landing();

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })}
```

But im not sure if the current store is deleted. 
This is my reducer code:

```
case SIGN_OUT:
      return state;
```

the state is referring to my initial state:

```
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior of your reducer is to take the existing state and apply modifications passed on the action taken. From the reducer docs:

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an
>   action, and returns the next state.
>
> `(previousState, action) => newState`

By simply returning the state passed in, you are retaining the same state that existed prior to the execution of your reducer.

To clear the state, you want to return the initial state.

```
case SIGN_OUT:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
```

Comment: I tried to that, 

but im getting an error it says that "Type Error: Cannot read property Name of 'null',

Comment: That's probably due to something on your landing page expecting something not covered by your initial state (or your `INITIAL_STATE` is incorrect). Hard to say for sure. You'd have to do some debugging to figure that part out.